# Solving a differential equation $e^xf'_v + e^xf''_{uv} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

We have the following differential equation:

$e^xf'_v + e^xf''_{uv} = 0$ where $u=x$ and $v=ye^x $.

This is part of a bigger problem, but this is the part that I come to and I have no idea what to do next.

The solution is meant to be on the form $f(x,y)$.

Comment: $e^x\neq0$ and $\dfrac{d}{dv}(f+f_u)=0$.

Comment: I got that too, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Because if I integrate it twice I will have $F$ in the answer

Comment: Thus $f(x,y)=g(u)+e^{-u}h(v)=g(x)+e^{-x}h(ye^x)$ for some functions $g$ and $h$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got your result?